# Add a user by another user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User devise model. Is there any way to add a user to the same user devise model by an already registered user?

1. User A makes registration.
2. User A confirms an email.
3. User A becomes admin.
4. User A adds another user B using email.
5. Email verification is sent to user B.

I have done the first three steps. Pleas provide me an idea to do the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

devise_invitable https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable is the best solution i found out.

Below providing the steps:

Assuming you created the devise user model and configured the action mailer.

1. add`gem 'devise_invitable`
2. In your cmd `bundle install`
3. `rails generate devise_invitable:install`
4. `rails generate devise_invitable user`
5. `rake db:migrate`
6. `rails generate devise_invitable:views users`
7. Now in your browser sign up or sign in to an already registered account.
8. Goto `http://localhost:3000/users/invitation/new` .
9. here you can provide the email id of whom you want to invite.